# Need to sync 104 Gitlab repositories with Github using one-way sync. Any ideas?

Tags: github, gitlab

I am working on three different Gitlab server managed by different pro instances, and I would like to gather my repositories onto Github. I basically would like to sync one-way from Gitlab to Github all of them. Is there any idea here how to do that ?

I have managed to do it for one repositories but I have approximately 104 all platforms put together. https://dev.to/brunorobert/github-and-gitlab-sync-44mn

I have a least a complete list (text file) of all repositories I would like to sync. Anybody already done that ? Cheers !

M.

Comment: Just a general idea, but with some scripting you could use the GitLab API to achieve the same setting you did manually to mirror the repositories https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/remote_mirrors.html#create-a-pull-mirror

Comment: GitLab API Works like a charm! Many thanks @Jhilton